# Arc length and chord only.

Tags: circles

Hello everyone hope you are all well.

Is it possible to find the radius of a circle if the only information you have is arc length and its associated chord?

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: Yes, but you have to invert $\sin(x)/x$.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from @orangeskid's answer, you can *almost* have the analytical solution of the equation
$$\frac{c}{a} = \frac{\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})}{\frac{\theta}{2}}$$ Let $k=\frac{c}{a}$ and $x=\frac{\theta}{2}$ to make
$$k x=\sin(x)$$ Now, for a first approximation, use the $1,400$ years old approximation
$$\sin(x) \simeq \frac{16 (\pi -x) x}{5 \pi ^2-4 (\pi -x) x}\qquad \qquad(0\leq x\leq\pi)$$ which gives
$$x_0=\frac{\pi  k-4+2 \sqrt{-\pi ^2 k^2+2 \pi  k+4}}{2 k}$$ and now, perform one single iteration of Newton method
$$x_1=\frac{\sin (x_0)-x_0 \cos (x_0)}{k-\cos (x_0)}$$
Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
k & x_0 & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 0.05 & 2.99294 & 2.99146 &  2.99146 \\
 0.10 & 2.85371 & 2.85234 &  2.85234 \\
 0.15 & 2.72180 & 2.72114 &  2.72114 \\
 0.20 & 2.59560 & 2.59574 &  2.59574 \\
 0.25 & 2.47378 & 2.47458 &  2.47458 \\
 0.30 & 2.35522 & 2.35644 &  2.35644 \\
 0.35 & 2.23894 & 2.24033 &  2.24033 \\
 0.40 & 2.12403 & 2.12535 &  2.12535 \\
 0.45 & 2.00960 & 2.01068 &  2.01067 \\
 0.50 & 1.89477 & 1.89549 &  1.89549 \\
 0.55 & 1.77859 & 1.77894 &  1.77894 \\
 0.60 & 1.65996 & 1.66003 &  1.66003 \\
 0.65 & 1.53760 & 1.53761 &  1.53761 \\
 0.70 & 1.40988 & 1.41019 &  1.41019 \\
 0.75 & 1.27459 & 1.27570 &  1.27570 \\
 0.80 & 1.12856 & 1.13111 &  1.13110 \\
 0.85 & 0.96677 & 0.97138 &  0.97135 \\
 0.90 & 0.78035 & 0.78676 &  0.78668 \\
 0.95 & 0.55016 & 0.55192 &  0.55191
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is interesting. Notice that if the angle at center is $\theta$ ($0\le \theta \le 2\pi$) then
$$c = 2 R \sin \frac{\theta}{2}\\
a = R \theta$$

From here we get
$$\frac{c}{a} = \frac{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}{\frac{\theta}{2}}$$

Now, on the interval $[0, \pi]$ the function $\phi \to \frac{\sin\phi}{\phi}$ is strictly decreasing, with image $[0, 1]$.

Therefore, knowing $c$, $a$, get $\frac{c}{a}$, then $\phi\colon = \frac{\theta}{2}$, and then $R$.

Example: $c=10$, $a=12$. With $\phi\colon = \frac{\theta}{2}$ we get
$$\frac{\sin \phi}{\phi} = \frac{10}{12}$$
and so $\phi= 1.0267\ldots$ and
$$R = \frac{a}{2 \phi} = \frac{12}{2 \cdot 1.0267\ldots} = 5.8437\ldots$$

Note: this allows calculating the radius of a circle when we have access only to a portion of it.

Comment: @peterwhy: I edited the answer to include the case $0\le \theta \le 2 \pi$ as you suggested. Great point, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried?

HINT

Can you draw a figure of chord and arc?

$$ s= R \theta;\quad L= 2 R \sin \theta/2; $$

A series approximation is computable to any degree of approximation depending on the number of terms chosen in sine series

$$ \dfrac{L}{2R}= \dfrac{s}{2R}-\dfrac{(s/2R)^3}{3!} +\dfrac{(s/2R)^5}{5!} - ...$$

Comment: $L = 2R\sin(\theta/2)$

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I am having trouble using the formula you mentioned as I can't determine either the central angle or the radius from just the chord length and arc alone. If for example the arc is 561 mm and the chord is 540 how would that fit into the equation?

Comment: @eyeballfrog: Thanks, corrected typo.